# Scriptures about announcement of possessing mantra siddhi

Tags: scripture, mantras, siddhi

Suppose a person attains siddhi over a particular mantra.

Is it recommended by scriptures to hide about possession of such siddhi from public?

Comment: Siddhis must be kept secret. Showing or not can be possible only by Guru or Divine order.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how should I explain in which sadhana I read it, (also I am not sure of its validity in all sadhanas) in [Nila-Saraswati tantra](https://archive.org/details/NilaSarasvatiTantramS.N.Khandelwal/page/n131/mode/2up)(16th Ulhassa), 119th verse:

> तेन चेन्निधनं न स्यात्तदा देवी प्रकुप्यति।
> त्रिरात्र वाथ षड्रात्र नवरात्रचत्व गोपयेत्‌ ॥

Forget about the first line, the second line says a person who has attained siddhi must keep it secret for 3 nights or 6 nights or 9 nights.

Found one more for Kundalini shakti.

> कुन्डलीशवितसिद्धि: साद्वर्णकोटिशतैरपि।
> तस्मात्त्वयापि गिरिजे गोपनौय प्रयत्नतः॥

Through the means of 100 crore varnas, one obtains the siddhi of Kundalini shakti, one must by all means keep it secret. (KankalMalini tantra)